# Dynamic Projections stopped working after upgrade to Spring Boot 3.2.1

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-projections

[This](https://github.com/Martin-BG/Marketplace) project stopped working after upgrade from Spring Boot `3.2.0` to `3.2.1`.

The error message is quite long and nested and points to a problem with `GenericRepository#findProjectedById` method (***At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query***):

```
2024-01-09T21:02:14.081+02:00  WARN 25839 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig' defined in file [/home/martin/Dev/Marketplace/target/classes/bg/softuni/marketplace/config/WebSecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [/home/martin/Dev/Marketplace/target/classes/bg/softuni/marketplace/service/UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in bg.softuni.marketplace.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.Optional bg.softuni.marketplace.repository.GenericRepository.findProjectedById(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Class); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional bg.softuni.marketplace.repository.GenericRepository.findProjectedById(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Class); At least 2 parameter(s) provided but only 1 parameter(s) present in query
```

The `findProjectedById` method uses a [dynamic projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/data-commons/repositories/projections.html#projection.dynamic) and is defined in the `GenericRepository` interface as follows:

```java
@Validated
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericRepository<E, I> extends JpaRepository<E, I> {

    <T extends Viewable<E>> Optional<T> findProjectedById(@NotNull I id, @NotNull Class<T> projection);
//...
}
```

`GenericRepository` interface in turn is used by the `UserRepository`:

```java
@Validated
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GenericRepository<User, UUID> { 
//...
}
```

The method is used only once in the code in `UserServiceImpl`:

```java
    @Override
    public Optional<String> getUsernameById(@NotNull UUID id) {
        return userRepository
                .findProjectedById(id, UserUsernameProjection.class)
                .map(UserUsernameProjection::getUsername);
    }
```

And here is the `UserUsernameProjection` interface:

```java
public interface UserUsernameProjection extends Viewable<User> {

    String getUsername();
}
```

Release Notes of [Spring Boot 3.2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v3.2.1) or [Spring Framework 6.1.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v6.1.2) miss information of a breaking change like that and I wasn't able to find other mentions of such problem here, so any hints in the right direction will be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Would you mind creating an issue in Spring Data Commons and provide a more minimal reproducer? I've tried `mvn clean test` but it runs fine as soon as I start the Docker containers.

Comment: Nevermind. Just realized that the project is on 3.2.0. I see it fail on 3.2.1 then.

Comment: I created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/3020 to address the issue.

Comment: @mp911de Thank you very much for investigating and taking care of the issue!